# Mailman auto-approve postings by members of nested lists

Tags: mailman

I have an umbrella configuration on mailman, and postings to the top list from members of the nested lists will be held for approval, something I do not want, I want them to be auto-approved. The main problem is that there are email addresses from multiple domains, so a regex sender filter (or a dozen) won't suffice.

Is there any way to accomplish this?